# Nav bar not becoming sticky?

Tags: html, css

can anyone tell me why is my nav bar not following sticky position property.

HERE IS THE LINK TO MY CODE--https://codepen.io/prashant_verma/full/yLMKMQL

Comment: Post your code in your question please. We need a [mcve] here, not on another site

Comment: there is no JS. From memory the `sticky` class will require JS http://stickyjs.com

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed`

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: lightblue;
  
} 

p {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <h1>Hello World</h1>
</header>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eleifend, est at consequat facilisis, sapien nunc pharetra nunc, eu gravida quam massa vel sapien. Vivamus suscipit dui quis erat consectetur, a euismod enim varius. Curabitur quis dolor sed dolor aliquet pharetra. Phasellus eu malesuada turpis. Sed condimentum, augue et condimentum laoreet, leo enim ultrices justo, sit amet congue est lacus a ipsum. Ut posuere mi ac mi sagittis, ut fermentum dolor condimentum. Morbi aliquam egestas lacus et suscipit. Fusce sodales sollicitudin ex eget pulvinar. Nunc velit dui, rutrum vitae lacinia id, sodales vitae sem. Vivamus interdum nibh auctor massa tempus, non sollicitudin risus tincidunt. Donec tortor enim, volutpat a nunc non, placerat semper ex.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eleifend, est at consequat facilisis, sapien nunc pharetra nunc, eu gravida quam massa vel sapien. Vivamus suscipit dui quis erat consectetur, a euismod enim varius. Curabitur quis dolor sed dolor aliquet pharetra. Phasellus eu malesuada turpis. Sed condimentum, augue et condimentum laoreet, leo enim ultrices justo, sit amet congue est lacus a ipsum. Ut posuere mi ac mi sagittis, ut fermentum dolor condimentum. Morbi aliquam egestas lacus et suscipit. Fusce sodales sollicitudin ex eget pulvinar. Nunc velit dui, rutrum vitae lacinia id, sodales vitae sem. Vivamus interdum nibh auctor massa tempus, non sollicitudin risus tincidunt. Donec tortor enim, volutpat a nunc non, placerat semper ex.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because position sticky always follows its parent height and width. In your case, `#sticky` is inside its parent `<header>` and header has the least minimum height, that's why when you are passing the header, `#sticky` is following so. So,the solution is, you rather keep the `#sticky` in such a position so that `<body>` can be its parent. like this,

```
<body>
  <div id="sticky">
  ...
  </div>
<body>
```

then it will stick on top always across the page.
And if you want to place it under the h1 - Flexbox challenge 2,
give it top: (the height of the h1)
Though position: fixed is an easy solution for you, you must know position sticky well also